# I need to implement search (Like find in page) . I have rendered an XML in my HTML page. I need to search for a text in this rendered XML

Tags: angular, full-text-search, ignite-ui-angular

I need to implement search (Like find in page) . I have rendered an XML in my HTML page. I need to search for a text in this rendered XML. I have set the XML as the innerhtml of a div. 
I have used IgxTextHighlightDirective for searching and highlighting the search text.

This is my data

```
        this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(xmld);
```

And this is what i have written in my HTML template

```
<div class="xml-view" (dblclick)="selectEntryText($event)">
    <div [innerHTML]="htmlData" igxTextHighlight [value]="htmlData" class="search-text">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: The below given is the result Before searching]

After typing in the search box. This is my problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you had the chance to check the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't added the [necessary styles](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-highlight-directive?file=src%2Fstyles.scss). Also, for what exactly you use the `innerHtml` input? As I can see you've correctly set the `value` input and as long as you execute the [`find`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-highlight-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftext-highlight-sample-1%2Ftext-highlight-sample-1.component.ts) equivalent of your logic, the search capabilities should be working fine.

Check out [this sample](https://angular-text-highlight-directive.stackblitz.io) and [topic](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/texthighlight.html#usage) for more information on how to use the text highlight directive

```
private find(increment: number) {
    if (this.searchText) {
        this.matchCount = this.highlight.highlight(this.searchText, this.caseSensitive);
        this.index += increment;

        this.index = this.index < 0 ? this.matchCount - 1 : this.index;
        this.index = this.index > this.matchCount - 1 ? 0 : this.index;

        if (this.matchCount) {
            IgxTextHighlightDirective.setActiveHighlight("group1", {
                index: this.index
            });
        }
    } else {
        this.highlight.clearHighlight();
    }
}
```

[image]